# Eliminar seguridad de un PDF (usuario y contraseña) con C#

Tags: c#, pdf, login, itextsharp

Tengo problemas con unos documentos en PDF, cuando se trata de eliminar contraseña no tengo problemas (uso itextsharp.dll) pero lo que necesito es poder abrir y eliminar esa seguridad cuando el PDF viene tanto con usuario como con contraseña.

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería, pues no veo nada de información.
Tiene que hacerse con C#

Adjunto una captura de la ventana que aparece al abrir el PDF.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: El usuario y la contraseña los conoces?

Comment: Buenas Salvador, conozco usuario y contraseña. Pero necesito desproteger el pdf

Answer (score -2):

Estuve buscando en Internet y lo que encontré es un código que lo puedes implementar, es bastante extenso (está en inglés), así que te voy a dejar el link, a ver si te sirve...

Sino te sirve, avísame, mientras tanto, seguiré buscando mas información acerca de tu problema.

Link: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/cpp/EncTest

-Laullex

Comment: Buena iniciativa de tu parte ayudar a buscar una solución a la pregunta, pero por favor evita solo colocar un enlace sin parte del codigo que ayude a resolver el problema, ya que si se rompe el enlace se pierde la respuesta. Revisa [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: El link que pusiste en tu respuesta habla de C++, no C#

Comment: Laullex, gracias por la ayuda. Pero siendo de C++ no se si me va a valer. Además ojeandolo un poco por encima tampoco tengo claro si sirve para mi caso en concreto, pues como ya comento eliminar un password normal no hay problema. El lío es con la ventana esa de arriba. Igualmente que gracias por la aportación.